# ListView problem: it does not Jump to the selected item

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

Ok I am saying  lsvAvailable.Items[index].Selected = true;
and HideSelection is false so it shows the gray back color on the selected item, which is what I want .. but if the found item is somewhere down the list so I need scrolling to SEE it. it does Not JUMP to that item...and still I need to ba able to continue typing ( let's say I am typing in a text box like a search box and it is showing the item in the listView)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Call the [ListViewItem.EnsureVisible](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listviewitem.ensurevisible%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) method:

```
lsvAvailable.Items[index].EnsureVisible();
```